# How can I do this regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string, and I have to do 2 things on jQuery/javascript :

1. remove ALL characters (number, symbol, and so on) before the first alphabetic char (a-zA-Z);
2. save the removed string in a variable; save the resul in another;

Tried (with some suggestions on SO) [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeGqV/) :

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var parts = str.split(/^[^a-zA-Z]+/);
alert(parts[0]);
alert(parts[1]);
```

but it doesnt save the removed string. Any helps?

Comment: regex are best described by sample data and sample output or in your case, what do you want to be in `parts[0]` and `parts[1]`.

Comment: parts[0] should be the removed string, parts[1] the string after the regex. Is this your question? :)

Comment: You still didn't use an example. Do you need `00 - 12:` in `parts[0]` and `a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!` in `parts[1]`?

Comment: Yes man! Sorry I think was clear :)

Comment: No worries, but have it in mind to provide samples when you ask for regex. In a glance, I could see @ace's solution is the closest to what you have and it will provide with what you want.

Comment: @Shef : yes but seems that this solution have got an error :( Check the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the str.match function, and match everything before the first alphabetic character:

http://jsfiddle.net/R9HtC/

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var parts = str.match(/^(.*?)([a-zA-Z].*)/);
alert(parts[0]);
alert(parts[1]);
alert(parts[2]);
```

(.*?) does a match of everything, but *? makes it non greedy, in that it finds the shortest match possible before the first alphabetic character.

**EDIT**

If you want to cater for the case where there is no alphabetic character, the following works:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3RGn/

```
var str = '00 - 12:';
var parts = str.match(/^(.*?)([a-zA-Z].*)?$/);
alert(parts[0]);
alert(parts[1]);
alert(parts[2]);
```

And in this case parts[2] is undefined. We use a ? to make the alphabetic match optional, and the $ to anchor the match to the whole string, so we still match everything if there is no alphabetic character.

Answer (score 2):

I think capturing groups would be a good option

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var regex /(.*?)([a-zA-Z].+)/
var match = regex.exec(str);
```

Then access the groups like match[1]

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think you want what you say, because this is pretty close:

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var before = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+.*$/, '');
var after = str.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z]+/, '');
```

See it at: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya8Yb/

The problem is that your 12:a contains with a letter.

An alternative is to try to match the pattern better:

```
var parts = str.match(/^(.*? - \b)([a-zA-Z].*)/);
document.write('<pre>'+str+"\n"+parts[1]+"\n"+parts[2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7JuhV/3/

This latter one results in:

```
00 - 12:a - 
Hello Maeco 4 !!!
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses in your regular expression to extract different substrings using `exec`, noting that it will return an array where the first element is what the whole regex matched with subsequent elements corresponding to each of the substrings:

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var parts = /^([^a-zA-Z]+)(.*)/.exec(str);

alert(parts[0]); // what the whole regex matched: the whole string
alert(parts[1]); // the first part, "00 - 12:"
alert(parts[2]); // the rest, "a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!"
```

EDIT: Note that it doesn't actually *remove* anything from the original string, it doesn't change the `str` variable at all. If you want to *remove* the first part add `str = parts[2];`.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/vb6Ce/1/

```
var str = '00 - 12:a - Hello Maeco 4 !!!';
var parts = str.match(/([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*.*)/);
alert(parts[1]);
alert(parts[2]);
```

`parts[1]` contains the removed string.
`parts[2]` contains the rest of the string.

Comment: Yes seems to be the best solution, but not with `var str = '00 - 12:';` Tried editing with `var parts = str.match(/(.*?)([a-zA-Z].*?)/);` but can't resolve this trouble...

Comment: This can be done with a small modification. See my answer, and http://jsfiddle.net/y3RGn/.

Comment: Yes, Stephen's answer solves the problem by making the last part `*` which means 0 or more `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: I already tried with that way : http://jsfiddle.net/ZeGqV/2/ it still doesnt works...

Comment: This seems to work:) Dunno why the older one doesn't works :)

Comment: The older answer I provided always expects an `[a-zA-Z]`. I modified the first part to get anything that's not `[a-zA-Z]` and changed the 2nd part to be greedy with anything that starts with `[a-zA-Z]`.